# Changing a WPF Datagrid Row background color programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm facing issues when trying to change a `DataGrid` row in the code behind of a `WPF` app. My objective is to change the row color when the row is selected and when a button `Valider` is clicked. My code is shown below.
I found some answers but none of them where useful for my case.

```
 private void Valider_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow dataGridRow = InventaireItemGrid.SelectedItem as DataGridRow;

         dataGridRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
      }
```

When I execute, I get a `NullReferenceException`. The debugger point to the dataGridRow to be null (the row contains data though).

Comment: have you checked if the particular row is not null?

Comment: Yes! @mahlatse, as I said, the row does contain data, but the variable dataGridRow is null.

Comment: I don't know the why, but always try to make sure your data (`DataGridRow`in your code) is not `null`. You can do something like `if (!(InventaireItemGrid.SelectedItem is DataGridRow dataGridRow)
 return;`

Comment: @mahlatse I tried checking with ! Null, and I found that it's null, the issu is that i dont know why it's null.

Comment: Isn't the selected item a property of your ViewModel? e.g if your datacontext is of type A, then the secleted item is of A.B where B is some property of A, what you should be looking at is filtering the sender object, cast it to the appropriate type type.

Comment: "as" returns null if the object has not the expected type. Set a breakpoint and check the type of InventaireItemGrid.SelectedItem at runtime. Knowing that type should hopefully tell you how to find the corresponding dataGridRow.

Comment: @PeterHuber absolutly true, I figured it out, the corresponding class is named Row and not dataGridROW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` property refers to the corresponding object in the `Items` collection. You could use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to get a reference to the `DataGridRow` container:

```
private void Valider_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = InventaireItemGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(InventaireItemGrid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
    if (dataGridRow != null)
        dataGridRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

There are most probably better ways of doing whatever you are trying to do though, for example using data binding and triggers.

Comment: I already tried that while I was searching for answers, it did'nt work since the "ItemContainerGenerator" is obsolete in my framework and has been replaced by "GetContainerFromItem" method, therefore I tried this :             DataGridRow dataGridRow = InventaireItemGrid.GetContainerFromItem(InventaireItemGrid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
and I still get a nullreference.

Comment: In "your" framework? What are you talking about? And what does the SelectedItem property return?

Comment: It's not a wpf object it's a control that I added, it's called Xceed Datagrid (it has a nice grouping, searching and sorting features) and it does'nt have the "ItemContainerGenerator" property anymore. I know I should change the header of my question then.